# start menu and task bar is missing in usb live kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I booted my kali from my usb stick in live version. When the Kali interface came, there was nothing but only the wallpaper. No start menu, no taskbar, no folder icons. But mouse was working. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not used to Kali/Debian Linux. I assume you are using a recent distro of Kali 2.x with gnome3 as desktop manager. On gnome3 press the Windows-Key to bring up the so called "Activities Overview", an overview of all running programs and search function. To set up the task bar go to Tweak Tool and Settings Tool.
Usually, the taskbar is located on the top of the screen.